# ssh: allow all users for one IP, and restrict to one user for public IP

Tags: ssh, authorization

I have a server on a VPN. This server has a public address and has a gitlab instance on it.
I'd like to be able to connect with any ssh user from the VPN address, but restrict the access to the git user from the public address.

How can I achieve both things at the same time?

I'm already restricting access like this:

```
# Listen on localhost
ListenAddress 127.0.0.1
# Listen on public address
ListenAddress 1.2.3.4
# Listen on the VPN address
ListenAddress 5.6.7.8
```

I'm on an Ubuntu server system, using openssh version 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to achieve this using `Match` blocks ( localAddress)with additional AllowUsers/DenyUsers filtering in your [sshd_config](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/) file, like this (assuming 1.2.3.4 is your public address):

```
Match LocalAddress 1.2.3.4
    AllowUsers git
```

Comment: Bah, I was half way through a convoluted answer about `authorized_keys` and `from=`. This is much better.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Access is denied for all users with this configuration. Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: I tried prepending this with `AllowUsers *`, without success.

Comment: `AllowUsers *` or `AllowUsers git` alone do what they are expected to do. Adding the `Match` block makes ssh deny everything for every IP.

Comment: I'm using `ListenAddress` directives and noticed with netstat that sshd does not listen on anything as soon as I add the Match block. Is there an incompatibility?

Comment: As soon as I add a `Match` block, ssh doesn't restart properly, and `service ssh status` displays "ssh stop/waiting". Any pointers?

Comment: `sshd -t` displays "Unsupported Match attribute LocalAddress" I guess I'm going to try filtering on the client's address

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using AllowUsers, without a match block, like this:

```
AllowUsers git root@somepattern root@someotherpattern
```